# Is it possible to execute commands on the LOCAL host after an SSH connection

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I have a use case where I want a user to connect to a target host via SSH but I do not want to leave the private key behind (the private key is retrieved via an API)

Is this possible via openSSH or once the user ssh's to the target system can we no longer execute commands on the original host?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `LocalCommand`can be used

```
ssh user@host -o LocalCommand="echo hello > test.tmp"
```

Or in your case

```
ssh user@host -o LocalCommand="rm ~/.ssh/onetime_id_rsa"
```